# Alter collation of SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, ssms, collation

Is it somehow possible to change collation of a .sdf-file? I have tried Management Studio 2008 but it only supports version 3.5, Management Studio 2012 does not support SQL Server Compact at all as far as I can see, the SQL Server Compact Toolbox for Visual Studio does not seem to offer this possibility and ALTER DATABASE also seems to be missing - is there any solution at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a solution, the SqlCeEngine Compact method allows you to do that from code (it effectivly recreates the database file), or you can do it via my sqlcecmd command line utility.

```
sqlcecmd -d "Data Source=C:\data\mydb.sdf" -z "Data Source=;LCID=1044"
```

Download from http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com

Comment: that is so cool - once again your tools comes to the rescue (:

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to change the collation on a .sdf file you will need to re-create it as a database in SQL Server:

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE "file.sdf" DATABASEPASSWORD '<Pwd>' COLLATE <the_Collation>
GO
```

If you have it already established as a database then you just need to alter the database:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE <the_Database>
COLLATE <new_Collation>
GO
```

Then you can re-compact the database and it will have the collation you require.

Comment: I have already tried to use ALTER but it gives an error in keyword DATABASE - creating a new one is not a problem, so maybe the easiest would be to create a new empty database and script schema and dato frem old db to new.

Comment: A little more manual, but I think that would work without a problem. Sorry that my solution didn't meet your needs.